# php mysql_fetch_array() not working as expected

Tags: php

```
$result = mysql_query($strSql);
foreach($bestmatch_array as $restaurant)
        {   
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {   
                if($restaurant == $row[0])
                {
                    $value = $row[1];
                }
            }
        }
```

What I am trying to do is sort the result of array formed by query according to the values stored in $bestmatch array.

I don't know what I am doing wrong but the 4th line just seems to run once. Please help guys. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> php mysql_fetch_array() not working as expected

Your expectation is not right.

```
foreach($bestmatch_array as $restaurant)
        {   
            // This loop will only run for first iteration of your foreach.
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {

            }
            // everything has been fetched by now.
        }
```

That is a logically incorrect sequence.

You expect your inner loop to be called over and over again as many times as you have the outer loop run but record fetch does not work like that. For outer loop's first run all the rows in $result will be fetched and since you do not reset the counter after your while loop that means after the first run there will be no more rows for the next run.

**Solution?** Fetch the row from mysql first then use a simple `in_array` call to check whether that restaurant is there in your array.

```
$result = mysql_query($strSql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
     $name=$row[0];
     if(in_array($name,$bestmatch_array))
        $value=$name;
}
```

Comment: Got your point. But is there a modification by which I can achieve it.?

Comment: but it will not show the result in the same order as the $bestmatch_array. I want result to come in same sequence as in best match array. All the values are present in the result but I want to organize them as in bestmatch array.

Comment: If all the values are present and you want to match them to a fixed order why not the best match array itself? Since this is not a way to sort.

Comment: because bestmatch array has just the id. while the result generated by the query has around 100 fields.

Comment: That makes it even easier. Implode your best match array into a comma separated string then edit your query to say `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET($csvValues)` and then you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: got your point. I will just try it and will get back to you if I face a problem. Thanx a ton buddy.

Comment: Sorry there is one typo in my last comment. You also have to tell a field name to that sorting function. Like this ` `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id,"$csvValues")` `  replace that with the right field name

Comment: The field name is 'sn' and query generated is: select * from resturant_detail where (delivery_to like '%PE30%' or collection_to like '%PE30%') and rsstatus='Active' ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET('sn','7,8,14,9,3,2,27,15,41,36,38,40,37,35,19,1,44,6,26,43') but the result is still not sorted.

Comment: `sn` should not be inside quotation marks since it is a field name, so change `'sn'` to `sn`

Comment: That was one stupid mistake I made there. It is working just fine now. I don't have the required reputation else I would have up voted you straightaway. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Store the results of the query in the array first:

```
$result = mysql_query($strSql);
$results_row = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {   
            $results_row[] = array($row[0],$row[1]);
        }

foreach($bestmatch_array as $restaurant)
    {   
        foreach ($results_row as $key => $value) 
          {
            if($restaurant == $results_row[$key][0])
            {
                $value = $results_row[$key][1];
            }
        }
    }
```